# ANDROID_HOME in bitbucket pipelines

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I have the following bitbucket-pipelines.yml file as suggested in bitbucket's [documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/java-with-bitbucket-pipelines-872013773.html) -

```
image: java:8
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script:
          - bash ./gradlew build
```

I get the following error on running a build -

```
BUILD FAILED
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.
```

I don't know where the android home dir should be or is in a bitbucket pipeline runner. They haven't mentioned an export path either.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you have two problems here:

- The SDK is obviously not present. Which means you either have to download it in your `script` at runtime (not recommended, as slow), or include it in a custom-built Docker image or use another Java image wich includes the SDK.
- Then, set the environment variable using `- export ANDROID_HOME=/path/to/sdk` in your `script`. This might not be necessary if you find fully-prepared 3rd-party Docker image for your purposes.